# MJPEG Video Streaming over RTSP for Android

Tags: android, video-streaming, rtsp, android-videoview, mjpeg

I am working on an android application that tries to stream a video from a private server. The Video is of format MJPEG. I am wondering of RTSP will help me show the video if it is of that form .

To access the video from the server the user needs to be connected to the appropriate WIFI. I have made sure the connection is established. I just cant seem to get the video to stream. My code for playing the video is as follows:

```
    String vidLink = "rtsp://user:pwd@192.168.2.250/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi";
    //set up video streaming
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
    mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
    Uri video = Uri.parse(vidLink);
    videoView.setMediaController(mc);
    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Check the supported video formats for android http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html. Hope this helps.